# What is totalPoperty in store for pagingtoolbar extjs 4

Tags: grid, extjs4, paging, toolbar

Below is my proxy for my store... my question is what is the totalProperty? I have 100 records  that I am reading. but I want to display 10 records per page. Should the totalProperty be 10 or 100 on my json?

```
 proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'GridView/writeRecord',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            totalProperty: "count",
            root: "myTable"
        }
    },
```

and this is my JSON

```
{
"count": 100,
"myTable": [
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the docs

> Name of the property from which to retrieve the total number of
>   records in the dataset. This is only needed if the whole dataset is
>   not passed in one go, but is being paged from the remote server.

So it should be 100.

Comment: That's what I thought too... and that's what I have set in my store but my paging doesn't show page two.. it says page 2 on the toolbar but still displays page 1 data on the grid